# How can I make aa Array of pointers to functions in Java?

Tags: java, function-pointers

I have a lot of functions and want to use an array to call them.
I know how to do it in c++ but dont know how to do it in java.
Pseudocode of my intention bellow:

```
Array<function pointers> functionBook[100];
functionBook.add(function_0);
functionBook.add(function_1);
 .
 .
 .
functionBook.add(function_99);


void functionCaller(int i){
  functionBook[i](); // will call function_i()
}
```

Comment: Java doesn't have function pointers. It has `@FunctionalInterface` that you can use. Search about it.

Comment: Do not do this, but you could invoke functions using memory addresses through JNI.

Comment: @LppEdd With Project Panama you don't even need to write any JNI code. But Java methods are complicated, as they don't have a fixed address.

Answer (score 3):

Try using lambdas and functional interfaces:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Runnable> list = List.of(
            () -> System.out.println("first"),
            () -> System.out.println("second"),
            () -> System.out.println("third")
    );

    list.forEach(Runnable::run);

}
```

You can use any other interfaces, like Function<R, T> that can accept values, or create your own functional interface.

Comment: My error, edited, thanks